# Auto create new sheet and email a summarized view of responses in google forms

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api, google-forms

I'm doing performance measurement for my office. And I probably just need to be pointed in the right direction. But here goes.
I want to make a form that employees can fill out every day, these responses go to a google spreadsheet.
I want this spreadsheet to create a new sheet for every week and then at the end of every month email the results to my boss.

What are my options for auto creating a new sheet, emailing results and summarizing?

Comment: Definitely too broad to be answered. All this is doable but you'll need to put your hands on the basics of google apps.

Comment: I figured it might be just that - too broad.. Do you have a sugestion as to where i could start?

Answer (score 0):

Start by reviewing the [Managing Responses for Google Forms quickstart](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/quickstart/forms). Then look at [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable), the [SpreadsheetApp service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app) and the [FormApp service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-app).

One strategy for what you need would be to have a script that (based on a [weekly trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers)), [creates a new spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#create(String)) and then [resets the Form's destination to that spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#setDestination(DestinationType,String)).

That script can also have another [(monthly) trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers) that uses [MailApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app) to send a summary email to whomever you choose.